# How can I display dynamic table values as integers in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I display dynamic table values as integers in Pinescript?

I have created a simple table in PineScript, using the table.new function, which gives me an overview of different assets. It shows me the percentage change compared to the previous day. However, it is a float with over 10 decimal places. How can I declare that it should be displayed as int with only 2-3 decimal places?

I worked with the str.tostring function to show the percentage change.

```
table.cell(table_id = myTable, column = 1, row = 1, text = "VIX", text_color =#8C983D) 
table.cell(table_id = myTable, column = 2, row = 1, text = str.tostring(percentChange), text_color = color.white, text_size = size.normal)
table.cell(table_id = myTable, column = 3, row = 1, text = str.tostring(close1), text_color = color.gray, text_size = size.normal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_str%7Bdot%7Dformat) to specifiy number of decimals or use [`math.round()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_math%7Bdot%7Dround) to round it to the nearest integer.

```
s1 = str.format("{0,number,#.#}", 1.34) // returns: 1.3
s2 = math.round(3.14) // returns: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

str.tostring(values,format.mintick)